# Separate apple id in app store

Tags: apple-id, mac-appstore

### Context

I have a mac book from my company that I use for work. I am logged in there with apple id with my company email.

I also have a private mac book, where I am logged in with my private apple id.

I have a few purchases in the app store on my private apple id that I would like to use on the work computer. On the other hand, I wouldn't like to log in with my private apple id there, to avoid syncing content from my private iCloud.

### Question

Is there a way to somehow stay logged in with my work apple id but use different apple id in app store? What consequences would it have? I wouldn't like my company to have somehow access to my private apple id. I checked that logging with private apple id is allowed by the company policy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The account you use in the App Store is not connected to your iCloud account in System Preferences/Settings.

You can simply switch in the App Store Account menu.